# CentOS update package in install folder

Tags: centos, centos7, rpm, pxe-boot, kickstart

I was trying to deploy CentOS from PXE with an install directory extracted from latest iso (1611). Install failed (with or without kickstart) because of microcode_ctl package, after some researches I found out there is updated rpm that fix the problem.

My problem is : I don't know how to update the rpm in my install folder and keep CentOS installer work

Here is what I tried based on my research :

- Download the Packages and repodata folders and try to update with

  ```
  createrepo ./Packages
  ```

  and update repodata on server with new files, didn't work because no group
- Same but with groups from the `*x86_64-comps.xml` file

  ```
  createrepo -dpo . ./Packages -g /path/to/*-x86_64-comps.xml
  ```
- Same with `--checksum sha` parameter

For the 2 last methods I have "Error populating transaction" and "No more mirrors to try" errors at the first package it try to install.

Obviously it means I did something wrong and the installer can't locate the packages anymore, but I don't find what to do.
Any help or hints would be appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would not mess with the initial installation tree. Instead I would provide a second yum repository for important updates/drivers and use the following parameter in the kickstart file:

`repo --name=repoid [--baseurl=<url>|--mirrorlist=url] [options]`

microcode_ctl issues are often due to unsupported server hardware (either too old, or not yet certified for the given CentOS/RHEL release).

#### Minimal kickstart example:

```
install
url --url=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/
repo --name=updates--baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/updates/x86_64/

lang en_US.UTF-8
keyboard de
network --onboot yes --device eth0 --bootproto dhcp --ipv6 auto
rootpw secret
firewall --service=ssh
authconfig --enableshadow --passalgo=sha512
selinux --enforcing
timezone --utc Europe/Berlin
bootloader --location=mbr
text
skipx
zerombr
clearpart --all --initlabel
autopart
firstboot --disabled
reboot

%packages
@base
@core
%end
```

Comment: Not sure how to do this properly, is there a way to use this : [http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/updates/x86_64/](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/updates/x86_64/) ?

Comment: Thanks for your update, but I still don't understand what's wrong with my config : [https://pastebin.com/3bvHC6hS](https://pastebin.com/3bvHC6hS) (It says that installation source is not setup)

Comment: Hum... Somebody gave me a method to bypass the crash during the install : Retry the install until it works. And it did work after between 10 to 20 install...
Thank you anyway !

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by setting up the network and host name at the bottom of the installation summary page.  it was a pre-requisite (not automatic) and I didn't notice the obvious Alert at the bottom of the page!!